# Extend multiple probability measures to a single probability measure on a bigger sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\mu_i$ is a probability measure on $(X,\Sigma_i)$, $i=1,2$. Here $X$ is an arbitrary set, and $\Sigma_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.

I want to ask under what conditions, the following is true:

There exists a probability measure $P$ on $(X,\sigma(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2))$ such that $P$ agrees with $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. That is, $P(E)=\mu_i(E)$ if $E\in\Sigma_i$.

$\sigma(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$.

Clearly, we must have whenever $E\in\Sigma_1\cap\Sigma_2$, $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$. What are the additional conditions sufficient for the existence of such $P$? Does any one know any reference for such result?

More generally, what can we say when, in stead of just $i=1,2$, we have general index $i$ (countable or uncountable)?

---

In particular, I wonder if the following condition is sufficient?
$\Sigma_1\cap\Sigma_2=\{X,\emptyset\}$